# Basic Custom Event Tracking with Google Tag Manager and Analytics

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm attempting to get a (in my opinion) very simple scenario working with Google Tag Manager and Analytics, and running into problems.

- We have made a new Google Analytics (GA) universal analytics site.
- We have made a new Google Tag Manager (GTM) container for our site.
- We created a "tag" in GTM for our GA account, firing on "All Pages" to track page views.

Now we would like to track events using custom JavaScript, via the [dataLayer](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#events). For example:

```
$('a').click(function() {  
  dataLayer.push({'event': 'linkclickedtest'});
});
```

This just isn't working, at all. If I watch Chrome's console/network tabs, no data seems to get sent to Google. I've also installed [the Google Analytics debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) for Chrome and it doesn't show the event firing either. I must be missing something simple. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new GTM trigger based on the `linkclickedtest` event. Your tag should then be configured to fire on this new trigger.

Comment: This took me in the right direction. Talk about unintuitive. Here's the guide I found to help me even more: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6164470?hl=en

Answer (score -1):

Is jQuery loaded before executing this code? Try passing object to the dataLayer.push function as below:

```
$('a').click(function() {  
  dataLayer.push({'event' : 'linkclickedtest'});
});
```

Comment: My click event is firing correctly. I can add console.log calls and see it working fine.